# Python Requests in Postman Args

Tags: python, post, submit, postman

I have some problem with postman chrome;
i want to convert my code (python language) to postman argument,

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost/assets/update', json={'id':['abcde'], 'bucket': 'fghij'}, headers={'Authorization':'klmno'})
```

to postman chrome (post),

1. Header tab (Authorization : klmno) -- done
2. then, the body ? < -- problem

i'm trying to solve but, the result is Error decoding JSON data. Error: JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)',) JSON data extracted from the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{'id':['abcde'], 'bucket': 'fghij'}` is not JSON, it's a Python dictionary which `requests` converts to JSON for you. You need to use the result of `json.dumps({'id': ...})` as the body in Postman. You will note it has double quotes instead of single.

Comment: hmmm, how to convert the python post requests to curl ? i want this work with php language :)